# How to use namespace constants across files in php

Tags: php, constants

I have what may be a simple syntax problem, but have been unable to find an example. Consider these two files:

**foo.php**

```
<?php

namespace abc\def;
define(__NAMESPACE__ . '\MY_DEFINE', 'MyDefine');
class foo
{
    ...
}
```

**bar.php**

```
<?php

namespace abc\def\ghi;
use const abc\def\MY_DEFINE;
class bar
{
    ...

    public function getMyDefine(): string
    {
        return MY_DEFINE;
    }
}
```

On the line referencing MY_DEFINE I get this warning:

> psalm: UndefinedConstant: Const MY_DEFINE is not defined

When I call getMyDefine from a unit test, it gives me the error:

> Error: Undefined constant 'MY_DEFINE'

What am I missing?

Comment: Of couse it's undefined, where did you include the `foo.php`?

Comment: I must confess I'm not certain how this works under the covers, but our project directory is set up such that our directory structure matches our namespace.  So foo.php is under src/abc/def and bar.php is under src/abc/def/ghi.  If I add "use abc/def/foo" in bar.php it can find the foo class definition in foo.php.  So it wouldn't seem I wouldn't need to explicitly include foo.php for this to work.

Comment: That's because someone implemented autoloading classes to silently include the file for you, and please note it's **classes**, constants are not affected by this mechanism.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

shingo answered my question.
I was expecting autoloading to handle constants in the same manner as classes, but this is not the case.